# How to throw a 408 HTTP code in Mockito test?

Tags: java, http, testing, junit, mockito

E.g. I am able to throw a 403 with the below:

```
    when(...)
        .thenThrow(ForbiddenException.class);
```

However there doesn't seem to be a class for the Request Timeout HTTP code (408).

How can I throw a 408 in response to a given `when` clause?

Comment: If you are referring to the J2EE ForbiddenException class you may note that it extends javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException and it is provided along some other specific types but you can always create a ClientErrorException instance with the http status you need

Answer (score 2):

```
when( ... ).thenThrow(new ClientErrorException(408));
```

Note that there are two versions of the `thenThrow` method - one which takes an exception class as the parameter, and one which takes an exception object.  The first version causes an exception to be instantiated using the default constructor of the given class, at the time that an exception has to be thrown.  The second version just throws whatever you give it.

In this case, there's no class whose default constructor gives you a 408 exception, so you need to use the second version of `thenThrow`.